# How to move cursor and click on a specific pixel in java screen

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to move cursor to a specific pixel in the screen and click on it using a java program.

I tried to capture a screenshot then work on it but I am stuck.

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the `BufferedImage` that method `createScreenCapture` (in class `java.awt.Robot`) returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on a specific Pixel with the mouse using **Robot** class in java
and move it using `move` method.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class MouseClicker {

    static Robot rb;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            rb = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while creating object" + e);
        }
        rb.mouseMove(1360, 768); //this method takes two parameters (Height, Width)
        rb.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);//this method takes one parameter (BUTTON) to press it
        rb.delay(10); //this is the delay between every press
        rb.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);//this method takes one parameter (BUTTON) to release it
    }
}
```

For more reference you can see the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).